# Generating a Random Password with KPScript

Tags: powershell, keepass

I am working on automating a lot of my day to day deployment work, and this includes a lot of manual KeePass entries. I saw that they have an official scripting tutorial, plus some functionality for generating random passwords based on a profile set up within the application.

[Per KeePass' documentation](https://keepass.info/help/base/placeholders.html#newpassword), this is what I am trying to run:

> .\KPScript -c:AddEntry "Z:\file location" -pw:"keepass password" -Title:Test -Username:test -password:{NEWPASSWORD:/scripttest/} -GroupPath:General

The trouble is, the KeePass entry generates with the literal string password

```
{NEWPASSWORD:/scripttest/}
```

and not the actual randomly generated password from the scripttest profile. What am I missing here? KeePass' documentation is fairly sparse on this sort of thing. It's a long shot, and I can see this site doesn't have a lot in terms of KPScript stuff, but it's worth a shot. Thanks!

Edit: I have tried running this code in CMD as well, thinking it might be a problem with Powershell, but encountered the same result.

Comment: According to the doc you linked scripttest is supposed to be the name of a profile. Did you make a profile called scripttest? You are also able to omit it.` password:{NEWPASSWORD}` and it should use the default.

Comment: Yup, I've got a scripttest profile ready to go. It generates passwords like I would expect within the KeePass application. If I run with flag `-password:{NEWPASSWORD}` , the newly generated entry's password field contains `NEWPASSWORD` .

Comment: Ok.... that is different. So that does not have braces? The other example you showed had braces? `"{NEWPASSWORD:/scripttest/}"`. I think the issue is that PowerShell is treating that like a scriptblock. What if you just do `password:'{NEWPASSWORD:/scripttest/}'`

Comment: Sorry @Matt, adding the double quotes into the original post was a mis-type, I realized I should just format it instead but forgot to remove the quotes. When using single quotes in the script, the newly generated entry's password is `{NEWPASSWORD:/scripttest/}`. I understand that this issue is getting weirder, so thanks for your patience.

Comment: What makes you think this works in kscript? the doc for addentry doesn't mention that is supports the keepass 2 macros

Comment: That's an entirely fair point. I figured things would naturally work with KeePass 2.x, but I'll play around some more with other commands. https://keepass.info/help/v2_dev/scr_sc_index.html#editentry this one has a different flag for passwords, -set-password, so I'll try that out.

Comment: I think if you want to make random password using kscript you will have to do it yourself with an external utility.